# Add custom property to Log4mongo while logging in runtime

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I use **log4mongo/log4mongo-net** for logging .net Exceptions in MongoDB. and they are working fine, but i'm having problem in using custom field while logging error.
My appender looks like

```
<log4net>
 <appender name="MongoDBAppender" type="Log4Mongo.MongoDBAppender, Log4Mongo">
     <connectionString value="mongodb://localhost" />
     <collectionName value="testlogs" />
 <field>
    <name value="timestamp" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
 </field>
 <field>
    <name value="level" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
 </field>
 <field>
    <name value="thread" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
 </field>
 <field>
    <name value="logger" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
 </field>
 <field>
    <name value="message" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
 </field>
 <field>
<name value="userdata" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%userdata" />
 </field>
 </appender>
 <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
<appender-ref ref="MongoDBAppender" />
 </root>
</log4net>
```

and i'm invoking it as

```
 LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;
 ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
 MDC.Set("userdata", "Dinkar thakur");
 logger.Info("this is the default page 2");
```

I want to have field in runtime. Is that possible is yes can you please tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify any `<field>` mapping, then a standard document with all defined parameters will be saved, like in the following example:

```
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "message": "this is the default page 2",
  "properties": {
    "userdata": "Dinkar thakur"
  }
}
```

Take [THIS](https://github.com/log4mongo/log4mongo-net/blob/70bb23d4c3b9a3827a5a06f00e5d184fdf9d28bd/src/Log4Mongo.Tests/MongoDBAppenderTest.cs#L225) test as an excmple.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but can't we make both workable. I mean, I add the fields which are common to all, and add some specific fields at run-time where they are needed.